# How to use Union in find request in Cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0, union

I need to know how i can use Union condition with find request in cakephp because i have to select data with multiple conditions in the same field.

I have 3 models :

```
class Zone extends AppModel
{
  var $name = 'Zone';
  var $belongsTo = "Fournisseur";
}
```

And

```
class Fournisseur extends AppModel
{
  var $name = 'Fournisseur';
)
```

And

```
class ZoneTarif extends AppModel
{
  var $name = 'ZoneTarif';
  var $belongsTo = array('Zone');
}
```

And i want to get data from ZoneTarif with conditions :

```
conditions 1 : ZoneTarif.poids = 40  and ZoneTarif.zone_id=1
conditions 2 : ZoneTarif.poids = 50  and ZoneTarif.zone_id=7
conditions 3 : ZoneTarif.poids = 90  and ZoneTarif.zone_id=10
.........etc.
```

so how i can use Union with find :

```
$this->ZoneTarif->recursive = 2;    
$data1 = $this->ZoneTarif->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('ZoneTarif.poids'=>40,'ZoneTarif.zone_id IN'=>1)));
    $data2 = $this->ZoneTarif->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('ZoneTarif.poids'=>50,'ZoneTarif.zone_id IN'=>7)));
```

When i use a simple query i lost all jointures and tables Alias :

```
$v =  $this->ZoneTarif->query("SELECT * FROM zone_tarifs INNER JOIN zones 
                                              WHERE zone_id = 6 and poids = 10 and zones.id = zone_tarifs.zone_id
                                              UNION
                                              SELECT * FROM zone_tarifs INNER JOIN zones 
                                              WHERE zone_id = 4 and poids = 40 and zones.id = zone_tarifs.zone_id
                                            ");
```

Thanks for your help.